# Remove all array values with specific condition

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting bellow array output and I want to remove array only having this `[name] =>` and `[size] => 0`.

**Current Array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Penguins.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpozs13E
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 777835
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tulips.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpq66c41
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 620888
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

**And I want this Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Penguins.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpozs13E
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 777835
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tulips.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpq66c41
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 620888
        )
)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter)?

Comment: Use standard `foreach` and `if` statements, and sure RTFM.

Comment: looks like trying to upload multiple file upload.just validate your data which having 'name' attribute ...

Comment: Show your code, or even an attempt of what you've tried. Displaying an array and what you 'want' is something you generally hire someone for.

Comment: @l'L'l I am getting array from this variable `$fileResults = $_FILES;
 $fileResults = array_values($fileResults);`

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than that; you want the file uploads without an error; i.e.

```
$results = array_filter($_FILES, function($file) {
    return $file['error'] === 0;
});
```